# Model Comparison within Bayesian Gaussian Mixture Model framework

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution, reversible-jump

Suppose that we conduct a simulation study, and the model that generated the data is the following Gaussian Mixture Model.

$$f(x)=\pi_{1}N(x;\mu_{1},\sigma_{1}^{2})+\pi_{2}N(x;\mu_{2},\sigma_{2}^{2})+\pi_{3}N(x;\mu_{3},\sigma_{3}^{2})$$

Now, in order to estimate the parameters $\left \{ \pi_{i} \right \}_{i=1}^{3},\left \{ \mu_{i} \right \}_{i=1}^{3}, \left \{ \sigma_{i} \right \}_{i=1}^{3},$ we fit 2 mixture models with Reversible Jump Markov Chain Monte Carlo, so we let the number of components to change iteratively. The models that we fit are one with independent mean components $\mu_{i}$ and a model with dependent mean components $\mu_{i}$. The models are exactly the same except from the priors assigned to the mean components. Their difference are the following, the prior distributions for each model are

$$Independent: p(\mu_{1},\mu_{2},...,\mu_{K})\propto \prod_{i=1}^{K}N(\mu_{i};m,s^{2}) \ \ \ (*)$$

$$Dependent: p(\mu_{1},\mu_{2},...,\mu_{K}) \propto \prod_{i=1}^{K}N(\mu_{i};m,s^{2}) \prod_{i\leq j}a^{|\mu_{i}-\mu_{j}|\leq \delta} \ \ \ (**)$$

where $K$ is the number of components in an iteration of the Reversible Jump MCMC, $m,s$ are the mean and prior specification of the mean components and $a, \delta$ are penalizing parameters that introduce the dependence between the mean components.

---

My questions is the following:

Suppose that we run the RJMCMC and we have the posterior output for the parameters $\pi_{i},\mu_{i},\sigma_{i},K$. How, can we assess which model $(*)$ or $(**)$ is better for the data??

Some ideas that I have are:

1. Fix a number of iterations for the RJMCMC, let's say $M$ iterations. For this number of iterations calculate the Effective Sample Size of the density values estimate for some points $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$ and conclude which model for those $M$ iteration produces a larger Effective Sample Size.
2. Observe which model, converges quicker to the true number of components $3$.

Is there a better way to coherently compare those two models?

Comment: @Xi'an But why? Intuitively, if a model manages to identify the true number of components isn't that desired?

Comment: For a fixed sample with a fixed sample size, the selected model is not always the true model.

Comment: @Xi'an Hence, what is the best way to compare which model is better? Simulate data and see how close they are to the true mixture?

Comment: The Bayesian procedure is to compute the Bayes factor of (*) vs. (**). See our very [recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.05416) for ways of computing this evidence.